# How to upload customer profile image in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I want create a customer image attribute,so customer and admin can upload, update and delete profile image like avatar. I know how is this possible in magento 1,but not in magento 2
.If anyone have any idea please share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i, Hdid you get a solution ?

Answer (score -3):

create below module files. It worked on magento 2.1.4
Create : app\code\Sashas\CustomerAttribute\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Sashas_CustomerAttribute"  setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>           
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>  
        </sequence>   
   </module>
</config>
```

Create:  app\code\Sashas\CustomerAttribute\Setup\InstallData.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @author      Sashas
 * @category    Sashas
 * @package     Sashas_CustomerAttribute
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2015 Sashas IT Support Inc. (http://www.extensions.sashas.org) 
 */

namespace Sashas\CustomerAttribute\Setup;


use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;



/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Magento Username',
            'input' => 'image',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

Create : app\code\Sashas\CustomerAttribute\registration.php

```
<?php
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
            \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
            'Sashas_customerAttribute',
            __DIR__
        );

?>
```

Comment: Could you please give full answer?